# Wordpress Foreach, Pass Category ID variable to Display Posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, wordpress-theming

**I'm attempting to display:**

1. Linked Category Titles
2. Category Descriptions (trimmed to custom length)
3. Category "Readmore Styled Link
4. A lists of Post Titles WITHIN that category, linking to the posts

I've accomplished tasks 1-3 with a Foreach loop, but I can't seem to display posts titles WITHIN each category through methods I've used in the past. The main thing is that I can't figure out how to run get_posts(); or a function like it with a variable in the $args array.

I feel this really needs to be done with a foreach loop, as I'm working with 20+ Categories. I've tried mixing / matching with a 3rd party shortcode plug-in, but due to "order of wp operations" that idea failed as well :( Any help would be EXTREMELY appreciated as I've been spinning my wheels for the past 3-4 hours.

**Source Code →**
http://pastebin.com/Mm9u27dF

**Code Output:**

`<p class="topic-link-heading"><a href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/?cat=3" id="topic-link">Understanding Democratic Governance and Market Economy</a></p><p class="topic-list">There is an ongoing debate in academic circles and among practitioners on the linkages between democratic governance and market economies. It has intensified in light of transitions taking place after the fall of the Berlin Wall. Amidst expectations that all &hellip; <a href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/?cat=3" > Topic Overview &rarr;</a></p>3`

**Please Note**

The "3" is only being displayed to show that the category ID variable is outputting correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to display the posts for a specific category and you're having trouble doing it.

You're looping through the categories and I think you just need to use the [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) function to query the relevant posts with the specific category (I've taken the code from the official documentation):

```
<?php
 $post_args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => 5,
'offset'           => 0,
'category'         => $category->term_id, //in your case.
'orderby'          => 'post_date',
'order'            => 'DESC',
'include'          => '',
'exclude'          => '',
'meta_key'         => '',
'meta_value'       => '',
'post_type'        => 'post',
'post_mime_type'   => '',
'post_parent'      => '',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true );

// The Query
query_posts( $post_args );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

To check if the posts are getting queried or not do something like this:

```
 $relevant_posts = query_posts( $post_args );
 print_r($relevant_posts); //Should print an associated array with the posts.
```

So you could populate the `args` variable with the specific category that you're fetching within the `for` loop and then just query the posts. Once you have the posts, you can refer to the links from easily. This [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) also might come in handy while looping through the posts.

Comment: passing into the $post_args array 'category' => '$category' just shows all the posts from EVERY category which leads me to believe it is not being evaluated. If there a special syntax for, I guess you'd say rendering a variable before placing it in an array?

Comment: @MichaelRoach, it was just a template. The variable `category` would be set to the `id` of the category you're fetching.

Comment: I have edited my answer with the updated category id from the variable you're fetching. You don't have to surround it with single quotes. It would be considered a string and therefore try to fetch the posts with category `'$category'`. Also try to put the queried posts in a variable and print it, to debug any errors you are getting.

Comment: I had tried it with / without quotes, and I still get the same result, this is REALLY stumping me. The posts are being queried, but I think something funky is going on with the array. The print array just listed out all the published posts info from EVERY category at the end.

Comment: The solution:
query_posts( array('category__and'=>$test)); Full code: http://pastebin.com/Xr4rWJT3 I referenced http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pass-variable-into-category_and-array as well. I was like, what is this "__and" operator?

Comment: Well, I am glad you could get it working. The `category__and` basically allows you to give in a list or an array of category ids to fetch your posts from. I have edited my answer as per the solution. It should be `term_id` instead of `Cat_ID`.